# How can I write faster to the frame buffer on C?

Tags: c, graphics

I'm currently writing a program that involves graphics. After some thought I decided to write directly to the frame buffer on /dev/fb0 and the code is working great but the writing speed is slow. It takes 0.161s to write a blank screen (0.213s is the program with the fb0 writing and 0.052s is the program without writing to fb) which means 6fps without any 3d rendering. Is there a way to write faster to a file like the /dev/fb0 on C? I'm currently using `fb = freopen("/dev/fb0","w",stdout);` 
to open the file and the regular `printf`to write to the file, also the display is 320x240.
Thanks :)

Comment: 1. Turn off buffering; 2. Don't use `printf` - write into a memory buffer and blit it using `fwrite`. 3. Ensure you are using optimizations (`-O2` or `-O3`).  In any case, you should show your _actual_ code, not just try to describe what you're doing.  Maybe you're doing something insane like using `printf`to write one character at a time.

Comment: Depending on your hardware, you could replace the generic framebuffer driver with *fbvesa* - That is way faster.

Comment: @paddy after using `fwrite` instead of printing one character at a time with `printf` my program went from 0.213s total to 0.034s. Thanks a lot, do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the framebuffer device into memory using `mmap()` and blit to and from it with `memcpy()` or pointers.  Unless you are running X windows, in which case you need to go through an API such as X11, OpenGL or SDL.

Comment: http://betteros.org/tut/graphics1.php#dumb is a tutorial with more details.  One caveat: it just takes a guess about what buffer size is “more than enough space and assume[s] that it will always be enough.” Don’t do that with external interfaces that are meant to support every piece of graphics hardware that will ever be created.